# Sincronizar dos servidores MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, servidor, server

tengo un poco de duda con respecto a un tema que me están pidiendo solucionar en mi trabajo.

Espero ser claro y no enredarlos.

*Nota: No puedo usar servicios en la nube por politica de la empresa.

Tenemos un server local con MySQL en uns ciudad (CDMX), y desde otra ciudad nos conectamos por VPN a su sistema web, pero lamentablemente a veces se las va la luz o se les cae el internet, o viceversa, desde la otra ciudad falla el internet y se caen las vpns. El jefe pidió poner otro server en la otra ciudad y quiere "que de algún modo" cada ciudad trabaje de manera local con su server, pero que a las vez, estos servidores vayan sincronizando la base de datos.

Esto para que cuando ocurra algún problema de conexión pues el personal pudiera seguir trabajando con su server local y que posteriormente cuando se restablezca la señal pues los server se sincronicen, ya sea al momento o cada hora, tratar tener sincronizada la información pero que a la vez no choquen...

He investigado y pues no hay algo concreto, lo mas cercano fue sincronizar manera bidireccional ambos servidores como maestros y esclavos ambos al mismo tiempo.

https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/09/27/replicacion-mysql-windows-linux/

Pero tengo mis dudas ¿que pasa si algún servidor pierde la conexión por ejemplo una hora, al restablecerse automáticamente estos sincronizan y solucionan el conflicto de ids?

La otra opción que se me había ocurrido, es usar algún tipo de API, y que ambos sistemas manden ciertos datos a la nube y estos hagan los inserts y updates en ambos sevidores... pero eso implica mover ya código del sistema.

¿Alguien ha pasado por algo similar? de verdad cualquier consejo me ayudara, de antemanos muchas gracias y saludos!

Comment: Es complejo el tema, no el de sincronizar los servidores , sino el de la lógica del sistema supongamos que tenemos 2 server esclavos de un maestro que prevee data de stock de un producto y por una lado (ciudad) agotan un stock y en el otro aún sigue proveyendo, porque en el otro como se corto la luz no sincronizo las ventas realizadas, es complejo lo que podrían hacer es dependiendo de la lógica del sistema proveer de stock de data a 2 servers de manera independiente y rebajar del maestro dichas asignaciones y luego en la noche cuando ya no hay movimientos hacer que los esclavos actualicen

Comment: la data en el server maestro, es complejo mantener la info bidireccional si es que se corta la energía.